# DialogFragment not resizing for soft keyboard on >= API 24

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I have been googling and searching Stack Overflow 2 days, but haven't found something that could help me.

I'm trying to implement a DialogFragment that's fullscreen on smartphones and a modal dialog on tablets.

**This is how it is supposed to look (taken on an API level 23 device):**

[image: How it's supposed to look]

**This is how it looks on an API level 24 device:**

[image: How it's looking]

This works with the following code on devices with API level <= 23
I tested it on multiple real and emulated devices.

**TestDialogFragment.java:**

```
public class TestDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{
    private boolean isTablet;

    public TestDialogFragment()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        isTablet = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet); // defaults to false, true >= sw600dp
        if (isTablet)
        {
            setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar_MinWidth);
        } else
        {
            setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light);
        }
        setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle
        savedInstanceState)
    {
        if (!isTablet)
        {
            Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
            if (window != null)
            {
                window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
            }
        }

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        if (isTablet)
        {
            Dialog d = getDialog();
            if (d != null)
            {
                int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                d.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**dialog_fragment.xml:**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/dialog_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingBottom="14dp"
            android:paddingTop="14dp"
            android:text="@string/dialog_title"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edit_text_1"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/progress_bar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dialog_toolbar"
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="?android:progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/edit_text"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/edit_text"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/edit_text"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/results_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edit_text"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/no_results_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/no_results"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edit_text"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        tools:visibility="visible" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I can't figure out why this doesn't also work on API level 24 and up. I see no changes to this behaviour in the release notes for Android 24.

Is there anything wrong with my code or have I overlooked anything?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to at least get the contents of the dialog to be always visible by expanding [this](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/util/KeyboardUtil.java) class from Mike Penz's [MaterialDrawer library](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer). This isn't the prettiest solution, but atleast everything in the dialog can be interacted with with the keyboard open.

Here is the code:

```
public class KeyboardUtil
{
    private View activityDecorView;

    private View dialogDecorView;

    private View contentView;

    private int diff;

    //a small helper to allow showing the editText focus
    ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener activityListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout()
        {
            Rect r = new Rect();
            //r will be populated with the coordinates of your view that area still visible.
            activityDecorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

            //get screen height and calculate the difference with the usable area from  r
            int height = activityDecorView.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
            diff = height - r.bottom;

            //no difference means no keyboard, so remove padding
            if (diff == 0)
            {
                //check if the padding is != 0 (if yes reset the padding)
                if (contentView.getPaddingBottom() != 0)
                {
                    //reset the padding of the contentView
                    contentView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener dialogListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout()
        {
            //if it could be a keyboard and the view hasn't shrunk on it's own add the padding to the view
            if (diff != 0 && activityDecorView.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels - diff >
                    contentView.getHeight())
            {
                //the view shrunk on it's own. remove padding

                //check if the padding is != 0 (if yes reset the padding)
                if (contentView.getPaddingBottom() != 0)
                {
                    //reset the padding of the contentView
                    contentView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                }
            } else
            {
                // if the usable screen height differs from the total screen height we assume that it shows a
                // keyboard now
                //check if the padding is 0 (if yes set the padding for the keyboard)
                if (contentView.getPaddingBottom() != diff)
                {
                    //set the padding of the contentView for the keyboard
                    contentView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, diff);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public KeyboardUtil(Activity act, View contentView)
    {
        this.activityDecorView = act.getWindow().getDecorView();
        this.contentView = contentView;

        //only required on newer android versions. it was working on API level 19
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        {
            activityDecorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(activityListener);
        }
    }

    public KeyboardUtil(Activity act, Dialog dialog, View contentView)
    {
        this(act, contentView);

        if (dialog.getWindow() != null)
        {
            this.dialogDecorView = dialog.getWindow().getDecorView();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            {
                dialogDecorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(dialogListener);
            }
        }
    }

    public void enable()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        {
            activityDecorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(activityListener);
            if (dialogDecorView != null)
            {
                dialogDecorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(dialogListener);
            }
        }
    }

    public void disable()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        {
            activityDecorView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(activityListener);
            if (dialogDecorView != null)
            {
                dialogDecorView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(dialogListener);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Helper to hide the keyboard
     *
     * @param act
     */
    public static void hideKeyboard(Activity act)
    {
        if (act != null && act.getCurrentFocus() != null)
        {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) act.getSystemService(Activity
                    .INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(act.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
}
```